# How would I make a plane look defocused or blurry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, camera

I'm trying to make a product demo for a class and was wondering how to make a base plane look soft focused, like in this image. Would it be through depth of field or something else? I've tried depth of field, but can't get it like this. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: what can't you get that you see in this picture exactly?

Comment: The edge of the plane that the suzannes are sitting on. It's sort of blurred. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: are you talking about the edge of the light shadow?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure. It's like right at the edge of the base where it becomes blurry.

Comment: You must be talking about the light shadow, you need to select the light and tweak its Radius value (if it's a spot). If you want to play with the depth of field you need to select the camera and in the Properties panel > Object Data > Enable Depth of Field

Comment: It's actually an hdr, so I don't know if I can do that.

Comment: if you have an HDRI then you can disable its light on the scene (with an Input > Light Path for example)  and use lights only

Comment: Thank you for the hlp

Comment: le me know if it works  ;)  in Cycles it's even easier to disable

Comment: *"I've tried depth of field"*, what settings did you use? Defocusing in depth of field depends mainly on the distance and the f-stop used in the camera.